# How to subtract fix hours in an Excel formula?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I've been looking on the internet and here on the site, but I don't find an example: I would like to calculate the difference between two hours, but if one is in the morning (smaller than 12:00) and the other in the afternoon (larger than 13:00), an hour should be subtracted.

As the values "08:00", "16:00" and "17:00" are accepted by Excel, I thought this would be easy, something like:

```
=IF(AND(B3<=12:00,C3>=13:00),C3-B3-1,C3-B3)
```

But the values "12:00" and "13:00" are not recognised by Excel. How can I write my formula (as readable as possible, please, calculating 13/24 and using this constant in my formula is not very readable :-) ).

Comment: Can you try `=C3-B3-TIME(AND(B3<=--"12:00",C3>=--"13:00"),,)`

Comment: @JvdV: Thanks for learning me about the `TIME()` function, but I've opted for another approach, as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opted for this solution:

```
=IF(AND(B3<=TIME(12,0,0),C3>=TIME(13,0,0)),C3-B3-TIME(1,0,0),C3-B3)
```

This says precisely what I want: in case I started in the morning (`B3<=TIME(12,0,0)`) and ended in the afternoon (`C3>=TIME(13,0,0)`), then I subtract one hour `TIME(1,0,0)` from the difference (taking lunchtime into account).